# How to return type of Task<mytype> without running async

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asynchronous, async-await

In my data access layer I'm attempting to create methods with return types of Task.

I cannot get the return type from the entity framework to return `Task<List<MYtype>>`

```
   public static Task<List<ILeaf>> GetLeafs(int doorID)
    {
        using (var db = new StorefrontSystemEntities())
        {
            return db.proc_GetDoorLeafs(doorID).ToList<ILeaf>();
        };
    }
```

Is the only way to make this run correctly is to format the code like so:

```
 public async static Task<List<ILeaf>> GetLeafs(int doorID)
    {
        return await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                using (var db = new StorefrontSystemEntities())
                {
                    return db.proc_GetDoorLeafs(doorID).ToList<ILeaf>();
                };
            });
    }
```

The reason I was asking is because I would like to give the option to run async, or am I not understanding this correctly?
If I can just return a Task then on the calling end I could give the option to await if I wanted to run async, but if i wanted to run synchronously I would just call the method as normal.

If I'm returning a Task do I always have to include the async keyword in the method signature?

Am I thinking about this the wrong way? If I've got a return type of Task then the method has the option of being called async or synchronously?

But, if I have async and Task in the method signature then the method runs async no matter what?

Thanks!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So to answer the literal question asked, you can just do this:

```
public static Task<List<ILeaf>> GetLeafs(int doorID)
{
    return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            using (var db = new StorefrontSystemEntities())
            {
                return db.proc_GetDoorLeafs(doorID).ToList<ILeaf>();
            };
        });
}
```

That said, note that this isn't a particularly useful method.  The idea of leveraging asynchronous programming is that you don't want to have a thread pool thread sitting there doing nothing but waiting on this IO operation.  Ideally you'd leverage IO that is inherently asynchronous in nature; a method that itself naturally returns a task.

You aren't really providing value to consumers of your code by wrapping the blocking IO in a call to `Task.Run`.  If they need that operation to be run in a background thread they can do so on their own, and then they'll know more precisely that it's not a naively asynchronous operation.

See [Should I expose asynchronous wrappers for synchronous methods?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx) for more information on the subject.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I still get a little twisted on asynchronous programming, and you've answered it perfectly! So, from what I gather it's already being taking care of via IO. Thanks!

Comment: @AlumCloud.Com Well, no, it's not, not in this case.  My point is that *this isn't fixing that*.  Either the IO operation inherently offers an async implementation or it doesn't.  If it doesn't you can't "fix" that.  If it does, you just need to use it.

Comment: In this specific method call it is in my data access layer. I'm then calling a sproc that is in my Entity Framework. So, it doesn't offer an async operation "visibly", or I do not see one.

Comment: Ok, that link to the blog post was very helpful.

Answer (score 7):

```
public static async Task<List<ILeaf>> GetLeafs(int doorID)
{
    using (var db = new StorefrontSystemEntities())
    {
        var result = db.proc_GetDoorLeafs(doorID).ToList<ILeaf>();
        return await Task.FromResult(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: This method will run synchronously, not asynchronously.  This gives the caller the impression that it's an asynchronous operation despite the fact that it's not.  If it were a very short running synchronous operation you could get away with it, but it's not; it's a very long running operation.  If the caller of such an operation specifically wants to do the long running operation synchronously, but still needs a task, let the caller wrap the result in a `Task.FromResult` themselves.

Comment: @Servy Thanks for the suggestion. Changed the answer.

Comment: Best answer IMHO.